# Итерация по массиву на FASM

Tags: ассемблер, masm, fasm

Осиливаю FASM и хочу разобраться в процедуре сложения многобайтовых чисел для изучения длинной арифметики. Код такой:

```
format PE Console 4.0
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

start:
    call add_uint
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0

proc add_uint
    mov cl, [n]
    xor si, si
cycle:
    mov al, [b + si]
    adc [a + si], al
    inc si
    loop cycle
    jnc end_p
    adc [carry], 0
end_p:
    ret
endp  

section '.data' data readable writeable
    a       db 0, 34, 56, 78
    b       db 0, 43, 65, 230
    n       db 4
    sum     db 0
    carry   db 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable
    library kernel, 'kernel32.dll'
    import kernel, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
```

В строке `mov al, [b + si]` возникает ошибка error: value out of range. Попробую предположить, что либо ассемблер не может определить разрядность адреса в скобках, либо требуется указать, что копируется именно байт. Но изменение на `mov al, byte [b + si]` не помогает.

Код на MASM выглядит намного проще: `mov al, a[si]`. Как то же самое реализуется на FASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для адресации 32-битные регистры. Простая замена `si` на `esi` убирает ошибку.

Ошибка вызвана тем, что 32-битный адрес складывается с 16-битной переменной, причем размер адреса будет определяться по размеру регистров, используемых при адресации.

Используя 16-битные регистры при адресации вы меняете сам режим адресации для данной инструкции на 16-битный (если смотреть машинный код, то там будет добавлен байт-префикс смены режима адресации). А адрес переменной будет вставлен просто как число, причем заведомо не входящее в диапазон 16-битных значений, поэтому компилятор и выдаст ошибку "значение вне диапазона".

P.S. Данная ошибка не специфична для fasm. Думаю, если вы попытаетесь с помощью masm под Windows скомпилировать `mov al, a[si]`, то он тоже "ругнется".

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я пытался пробовать изменять размеры регистров, но действовал не в том направлении. А в чем проблема при сложении 32-битного адреса с 16-битной переменной? Почему не происходит приведение результата к 32 битам?

Comment: @typemoon, дополнил ответ.